# visual studio designer blend textblock width issue

Tags: xaml, expression-blend, blend

I have a project in visual studio blend designer...where there is a text box in the xaml view that has code like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="something" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
     TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{some.variable.is.here, Mode=OneWay}" 
     d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
     FontFamily="/Skins/Fonts/#Lucida Sans" FontSize="17" Foreground="#FF95A9BF"/>
```

For some reason this code just cuts off the string at a certain width, seems to be capped at 400.  If I try to add the width parameter to it like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="something" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{some.variable.is.here, Mode=OneWay}"
    d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    FontFamily="/Skins/Fonts/#Lucida Sans" FontSize="17" 
    Foreground="#FF95A9BF" **Width="800"**/>
```

it doesn't change anything.

How do I get this textbox to be a set width like 800?

Comment: You might mark answers as correct if you find them to be so, for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ditch all that WYSWYG IDE garbage it adds on there. Your `d:LayoutOverrides` is your culprit. Then just set the property. So that mess you have becomes;

```
<TextBlock x:Name="something"
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Text="{some.variable.is.here}"
           FontFamily="/Skins/Fonts/#Lucida Sans" FontSize="17"
           Foreground="#FF95A9BF" Width="800"/>
```

Blend is super handy and awesome, don't get me wrong there. However you'll want to learn some XAML too. Hope this helps, cheers!